# how to count how many an activity starts

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing my first application in android. 
I have two activities and I switch between them in my app
and I need to know how many times my first activity or second activity starts.

Comment: Your question is not clear..

Answer (score 3):

Make use of a static variable per activity and increment it in onCreate(), the static counter value will be your result .

Comment: i do it but its not work in each start activity its return to the first number that i passed to it

Answer (score 1):

did you try it this way?

```
static int count;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
count += 1;  

// your code here        
}
```

Comment: yes i tryed this but i have second activity and when i press a button in my first activity it goes to second activity and when i come back to this activity its number dosent change

Comment: try to put the `count += 1` in the onResume